# ggplotly function modifies line thickness and chart width

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I encoutered problems concerning lines thickness and charts width using `ggplotly` function (from plotly R package )

Here is my ggplot chart that I want to make dynamic using ggplotly

`graphe_clustering <- ggplot(data=dtaLngC, aes(x=DAT_RLV, y=vol_cso_norm))+
      geom_line(aes(color=contrat),lwd = 0.5)+
      facet_wrap(~Cluster, scales = "free")+
      theme(legend.position="none")`

[image: Obtained with ggplot2]

For now, everything is fine. But when I use `ggplotly(graphe_clustering)`, here is what I get:

[image]

There are two problems:

- Thickness of lines are too big
- Widths of charts located in the middle of my windows strongly decreased

Does someone has any advices concernings those problems ?

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example. But if I remember correctly I think `scales = "free"`is the reason it does that. Try to remove it and see if the graph is correct.

Comment: well done, thanks! if you remove `scales= "free"` , ggplotly keep your initial chart width. Any tips concerning lines thickness ?